# Como diminuir a logomarca ao rolar a página no menu fixo do Bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, css

Tenho um menu fixo com Bootstrap onde fica a logomarca:

```
           <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" id="logo" class="maxlogo img-responsive"></a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
    </div>
    </nav>
```

Porém ao rolar a página,como o menu é fixo, gostaria de diminuir a logomarca. Para isso tentei  da seguinte forma:

**CSS**

```
  .maxlogo {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999999999999;
    margin-top: -30px;
    width: 180px;
}
.minilogo {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999999999999;
    margin-top: -30px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
<script>
  $(document).on("scroll",function(){
      if($(document).scrollTop()>100){
          $("#logo").removeClass("maxlogo").addClass("minilogo");
      } else{
          $("#logo").removeClass("minilogo").addClass("maxlogo");
      }
  });
</script>
```

Só que ao rolar a página, ele está diminuindo a tag **nav** e não a logomarca. Como posso corrigir isso?

Comment: É porque vc está alterando a classe da nav e não da imagem.

Comment: Desculpe Sam. Funcionou. Obrigado!